# Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
at 
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.0.0.RC3.jar!/:5.0.0.RC3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M3.jar!/:2.0.0.M3]
    at com.zophop.gps.ZophopFrontEndServer.main(ZophopFrontEndServer.java:16) [classes!/:0.0.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
```

didn't get what was the error same code runs on other machine

Comment: Is that whole exception ?

Comment: Add configuration code and full stack trace.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue and nothing I already found is helping me here. Did you get this to work?

Comment: Check if another server is running already (in Eclipse, unless you are in debug view, it's hard to know). Try 'ps aux | grep "java\|tomcat\"' if you are using a bash-like shell. In windows, use task-manager (Ctrl+Alt+Del).

Answer (score 2):

I was using Java 11 and trying run Eureka Discovery Server using the Spring Boot application then it came up with this error when trying to run this application.

As they have remove Jaxb related libraries from Java 11 so you have add them as a dependencies.

Add the following in Maven POM file:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```